# Why do some .NET BCL methods not throw exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, base-class-library

For example neither the [BitConverter.GetBytes Method (Int64)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93ae9768.aspx) nor [XmlUrlResolver Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver.xmlurlresolver.aspx) are not documented as throwing exceptions. Are they indicating an error by using a return value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods do not need to throw exceptions if their logic cannot give rise to any errors. This is obvious in the case of `BitConverter.GetBytes`; the conversion is guaranteed to succeed for any `Int64` value.

There are some catastrophic exceptions that may be thrown by *any* method, such as `OutOfMemoryException` or `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: You mean `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: As for the `XmlUrlResolver` constructor, I just checked it in the .NET reference source, and here's how that constructor is implemented: `public XmlUrlResolver() { }`. Not a lot of ways for that to fail.

Comment: what if you pass in a value that is not Int64 ? or you cannot do that since you'll be warned  for that at compile time? If so, exceptions are not needed due to the compile time checking. What if the type could not be determined until runtime? shouldn't there an exception be thrown as well as catched  ?

Comment: The compiler ensures that you can only pass an `int64` into the `GetBytes` method. If you somehow do manage to compile it (by hand-editing the IL, for example), then the CLR itself will throw an `InvalidProgramException`, in the same class as `OOM` or `SOE`